# Ordenação de Dropdown Angular4

Tags: angular, dropdown, sortable

Olá,
Eu tenho um campo de estados(UF) que está como dropdown e gostaria de fazer a ordenação dele (por nome).
Poderiam, por favor, me dar um norte?
Meu código está assim hoje:

```
  estados = [
{label: 'Acre', value: 'AC'}, {label: 'Amazonas', value: 'AM'}, {label: 'Amapa', value: 'AP'},
{label: 'Pará', value: 'PA'}, {label: 'Roraima', value: 'RR'}, {label: 'Rondonia', value: 'RO'},
{label: 'Tocantins', value: 'TO'}, {label: 'Rio Grande do Sul', value: 'RS'}, {label: 'Santa Catarina', value: 'SC'},
{label: 'Paraná', value: 'PR'}, {label: 'São Paulo', value: 'SP'}, {label: 'Rio de Janeiro', value: 'RJ'},
{label: 'Minas Gerais', value: 'MG'}, {label: 'Espirito Santo', value: 'ES'}, {label: 'Goiás', value: 'GO'},
{label: 'Mato Grosso do Sul', value: 'MS'}, {label: 'Mato Grosso', value: 'MT'}, {label: 'Distrito Federal', value: 'DF'},
{label: 'Bahia', value: 'BA'}, {label: 'Sergipe', value: 'SE'}, {label: 'Alagoas', value: 'AL'},
{label: 'Paraíba', value: 'PB'}, {label: 'Piauí', value: 'PI'}, {label: 'Pernambuco', value: 'PE'},
{label: 'Rio Grande do Norte', value: 'RN'}, {label: 'Maranhão', value: 'MA'}, {label: 'Ceará', value: 'CE'}];
```

E no HTML está assim:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="estados" [autoWidth]="false" placeholder="UF"></p-dropdown>
```

Novamente, poderiam, por favor dar um norte?
Obrigado!

Comment: Como assim ordenar por nome??

Comment: Está vendo que no array está com os nomes (label) todos fora de ordem? Gostaria de ordenar pelo nome. Se fosse via select, eu faria um order by campo. É exatamente o que eu queria fazer nesse array.

Comment: Você quer ordenar os **label** porordem alfabética é isto? Tipo `Acre, Alagoas, Amapa, Amazonas, etc...`

Comment: Exatamente, @Le

Comment: Mas os dados são estáticos, ficam dentro de uma variável?

Comment: Sim, os dados são estáticos como mostrei acima. Ficam dentro desse array 'estados'.

Comment: Pq não os ordena lá mesmo na ordem alfabética?

Comment: Nesse caso daria certo porque não existem mais estados, mas, se fossem nomes de pessoas, por exemplo, eu teria que sair procurando onde ordenar ele?

Comment: Não entendi, as **options** não seriam fixas, receberiam novos valores?

Comment: Sim, as options são fixas. E eu quero ordenar ela, é possível? Você consegue ajudar?

Comment: Há algo do tipo:
Array := [aqui todo o conteúdo do array]
Array := Array.sort() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confesso que não entendi sua questão, sendo os dados que quer ordenar em ordem alfabética fixos, não entendi o pq não os ordena na variável **estados** mesmo, todavia, segue uma implementação:

```js
let estados = [
{label: 'Acre', value: 'AC'}, {label: 'Amazonas', value: 'AM'}, {label: 'Amapa', value: 'AP'},
{label: 'Pará', value: 'PA'}, {label: 'Roraima', value: 'RR'}, {label: 'Rondonia', value: 'RO'},
{label: 'Tocantins', value: 'TO'}, {label: 'Rio Grande do Sul', value: 'RS'}, {label: 'Santa Catarina', value: 'SC'},
{label: 'Paraná', value: 'PR'}, {label: 'São Paulo', value: 'SP'}, {label: 'Rio de Janeiro', value: 'RJ'},
{label: 'Minas Gerais', value: 'MG'}, {label: 'Espirito Santo', value: 'ES'}, {label: 'Goiás', value: 'GO'},
{label: 'Mato Grosso do Sul', value: 'MS'}, {label: 'Mato Grosso', value: 'MT'}, {label: 'Distrito Federal', value: 'DF'},
{label: 'Bahia', value: 'BA'}, {label: 'Sergipe', value: 'SE'}, {label: 'Alagoas', value: 'AL'},
{label: 'Paraíba', value: 'PB'}, {label: 'Piauí', value: 'PI'}, {label: 'Pernambuco', value: 'PE'},
{label: 'Rio Grande do Norte', value: 'RN'}, {label: 'Maranhão', value: 'MA'}, {label: 'Ceará', value: 'CE'}];
 
function comparar(a,b) {
  if(a.label < b.label) {
     return -1;
  }
  else if(a.label > b.label) {
    return 1;
  }
}

console.log(estados.sort(comparar));
```

Comment: LeAndrade, obrigado pelo retorno. Pode ser na variável mesmo, não tem problema. Eu entendi como você colocou aqui o retorno, só não entendi a sintaxe para fazer funcionar.

Comment: É um método do Javascript chamado **sort()**, que um dos seus parâmetros pode receber um função, e que no caso aí é **camparar()**. A função **comparar** simplesmente verifica se um parâmetro, no caso aí a primeira letra de cada label é maior ou menor em relação ao segundo parâmetro e assim por diante, ordenando os elementos dentro do array. Pode ler mais sobre o método aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Mas, eu consigo colocar isso de boa relacionado ao Angular? (não é o AngularJS é o 2/4). Desculpe se estou perguntando besteira, estou começando a fuçar agora nisso.

Comment: Tudo que funciona no javascript funciona no typescript que o angular usa.

Comment: Sim normal, pode atribuir assim por exemplo **estados = estados.sort(comparar);** e no `Html` usar do mesmo jeito que está fazendo com o Angular. Só que estados agora não vai ser mais a variável que estava desordenada, mas, sim o novo array ordenado.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, LeAndrade. Obrigado pelo auxílio.

Comment: Victor não sei como está seu nível de desenvolvimento aí, mas, aconselho dar uma estudada maior em Javascript que é base e depois partir para algum framework como Angular. Se a resposta lhe serviu pode marca-lá como aceita no botão V abaixo das setas ao lado esquerdo da minha resposta.